# In functionally programmed javascript, is there any penalty to returning a callback rather than just calling a callback?

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, callback

I do this out of habit:

```
function process( fn ){
  // Some process that builds data     
  return fn( data );
}
```

It is not always necessary to return the callback, and I would like to know if there is any performance hit in doing that over simply calling the callback:

```
function process( fn ){
  // Some process that builds data
  fn( data );
}
```

And if so, or indeed if not, then why?

Comment: Why do you ask? Are you having performance problems and suspect this to be the culprit? (Some people are starting to bristle at this predictable response on SO, but that does not make it any less valid)

Comment: No, I ask mostly out of interest because I want to learn as much as I can about functional programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no significant performance difference between the two.

Why: Adding the return value to the stack for use by the caller is a trivial op.

As they say, it's [de minimis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_minimis)

Comment: And so is that answer.  Nice and succinct!  Thank you!